# EHCache Disable/Shutdown

Tags: java, properties, ehcache

Is there a way to disable ehache externally using a property file?
CacheManager.shutdown() doesnt seem to work?
Actually we have 2 app with the same source code i require ehcache in one and not the other.
one where i dont need cache is a webapp!
Unable to figure to out yet how to go about this?

Comment: What other infrastructure elements are involved? are you using spring/hibernate or something? What role is ehcache playing.

Answer (score 2):

Setting this System Property to true disables caching in ehcache. If disabled no elements will be added to a cache. i.e. puts are silently discarded.

```
-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```